# How to make an edit view using django python?

Tags: python, django

I have edit_client view, Client model and a ClientForm. What I need is to edit an existing record from Client but display it as an editable form, and save the updated record. What should be seen in my views.py and my edit_client.html?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: @manetsus I also have and AddClient view. What I wanted to do is edit an existing record in the db using the front end. I need to get the record from the db and display it as an editable form, and save it back again/update it in the database using save()

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function named : edit_client into your view file.

As an example, you can use a link in your html like this :

```
<a href="{% "edit_client" client.pk %}> {{ client.name }} </a>
```

And your function can be :

```
def edit_client(request, client_id):
    client = Client.objects.get(pk=client_id)
    clients = Client.objects.all()
    if request.method = "POST":
        # what you want to edit (name, age etc ...)
        client.save()
        return render_to_response('index.html', {"clients":clients}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('edit_client.html', {"client":client}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Note that it will be different if you want to use a form.